# MacBook Pro (Late 2011, A1297) hangs on 'promiscuous mode enable succeeded'

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup, ssd

I am new to macOS and bought this late 2011 MacBook Pro second hand for someone. It booted once however now trying to get it to boot it hangs on

```
en2: promiscuous mode enable succeeded
```

I know that the last line is not always the problem, so I have attached a video of the boot in verbose mode. I cannot boot into OS X to get the logs.

I have tried resetting NVRAM (PRAM), resetting the SMC, reinstalling OS X El Capitan on it, Internet Recovery, (The actual recovery partition appears to be missing as the HDD was replaced) and AHT. Running AHT I get 'No issues found' so I am not sure what to do next.

I am not sure if that is all the info I need to provide, however if you require anything else, just ask and I will try and provide it.

You can find the video of the verbose boot here:
https://streamable.com/1xzci1

Comment: For information, the late 2011 MBP 15 and 17" have a known graphics card problem. Do you manage to start in single user mode (cmd + s during boot)?

Comment: Yes, I can start in single user mode. Is there anything I should do?

Comment: You can see this link : https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/force-2011-macbook-pro-8-2-with-failed-amd-gpu-to-always-use-intel-integrated-gpu-efi-variable-fix.2037591/